# My arrayList doesn't get successfully saved and restored?

Tags: java, android, file, listview, object

I have an activity which contains a listview, the activity (`MainActivity`) launches another activity (`HomeworkAddActivity`), this retrieves a string from the user and adds it to the listview (all of the above works).

However in order that the listview 'remembers' its contents whilest the other activity is launched I try to save the list to a file, code:

```
public void saveHomework() {
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(homeworkFileName);
        fos = openFileOutput(homeworkFileName,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        os.writeObject(homeworkItems);
        os.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void populateHomework() {
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(homeworkFileName);
        fis = getParent().openFileInput(homeworkFileName);
        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        homeworkItems = (ArrayList<String>) is.readObject();
        is.close();
        fis.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I then read it from the file.

`saveHomework` is called `onPause`

and `populateHomework`:

```
    @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    homeworkItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    activity = this;
    homeworkListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, homeworkItems);
    populateHomework();
    homeworkListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

However it only ever shows the items added by `addHomeworkActivity`, not those 'saved' and 'restored' (they don't get saved/restored successfully), why is this?

Comment: Make sure you have checked that homeworkFile exists or not! and also make sure of permissions if using external storage! everything else seems to be okay!

Comment: I didn't get your question, you have list (suppose call list A) and then you save while onPause, and then you restore while onResume()... and then what ?

Comment: @ashu i am using internal storage and i was under the impression that opening the stream populated the file.

Comment: @toonsuperlove the key point is that the save and restore dont work, i will/have updated the question. Also after onResume the list is put in the listview

Answer (score 0):

It has 2 problems

1. your listview still connect with your old adapter
2. notifyDataSetChanged might not work in your case, it relate to this answer

[notifyDataSetChanged example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example/5092426#5092426)

you need to reorder your command in onResume()

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    homeworkItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    activity = this;
    populateHomework(); // I move this line up
    homeworkListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, homeworkItems);

    //homeworkListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // this line might not work
    yourListView.setAdapter(homeworkListAdapter); // because your listview still connect with your old ArrayAdapter

}
```

Comment: I will try this, it makes sense, will let ypu know how it goes

Comment: Also, i believe, the notify... does work as the list updates with the new item (but the new item only)